# Trying to update Nuget Package fails

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget, nuget-package

I am working in a team environment where they have set up NuGet Stream to share some projects. I just recently got latest on one of my projects and noticed that packages.config is updated to refer to a newer version of a particular NuGet package. So I thought let me try to update package from my console so that I do have the latest version and Packacge.Config is pointing to the correct version

Now, VS 2015 NuGet UI does not even show an option to update the package(It has only two options Install and UnInstall). That's fine I can use Console and be done with it. So far so good.

Now, when I run the command to Update-package {packageName}. It throws following error:

> Install-Package : An error occurred while retrieving package metadata
>   for '{Package}' from source '{Server}'

So I thought may be it is corrupted. So let me remove the reference from the Package.config and then delete the folder from package  and then get the Fresh install. This time I did use the option -verbose. So I Fired the following command:

```
install-package Uas.AnalysisWorker -verbose
```

Which in response did throw same error at me:

with this detail:

> BadGateway http://Servername/FindPackagesById()?id='{Packagename}'
>   2262ms

May be the package at the server is corrupted or may be I am missing something else. But I do not want to contact package owner before doing my due diligence to make sure that I am not missing something Trivial.

- Also, on a side note I found some threads suggesting that updating to latest version of NuGet package manager solved their issue. I do have latest Nuget package so that shouldn't be an issue too.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error message, your problem occurs when retrieving package metadata from the url, you need to check the package source from Tools -> Options -> NuGet Package Manager -> Package Sources first. **Make sure the package source for the server is correct**.

To check if the package at the server is corrupted, you can try install other packages on the server. Or download a common package from the [NuGet.org](https://www.nuget.org/), like Newtonsoft.Json, set into the server(If you have permission), then install this package from the server, check if it works fine.

If all packages on the server (including Newtonsoft.Json) can not be install successfully with that error, the package source for the server should not be correct or the authority of accessing the server is limited.

If only one specified package can not be install successfully and Newtonsoft.Json also can be install, the package at the server should be corrupted. You could contact package owner.

Hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

None of these responses worked for me, using a private GitHub Packages Nuget repo it started constantly failing with the error:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at NuGet.PackageManagement.NuGetPackageManager
```

The only solution that finally worked (thankfully) was to **Uninstall** the Package and then re-install the Latest version that I was trying to update to.  I had to do this for each project that used the package.